# Best way to suppress C warning "Unused variable x"?

Tags: c, suppress-warnings

What is the best/neatest way to suppress a C compiler (for example GCC) like "Unused variable x" warning?

GCC's doumentation explains

> -Wunused-variable
> Warn whenever a local variable or non-constant static variable is unused aside from its declaration

I don't want to give any certain flags to my compiler to remove all these warnings, just for special cases.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to do this, e.g. take plugin development for a system, that expects your function with a specific signature like `void function_name(int par1, char *par2);` and you only need to work on par2.

Comment: In that case, write the signature as `void function_name(int par1, char*);` which is perfectly valid and won't generate warnings.

Comment: @spaceknarf If I do that with gcc 4.7.2 I get `error: parameter name omitted`.

Comment: I don't think it is valid to leave a parameter unnamed in a C function signature when it's part of the definition. It's acceptable in C++ though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found an article, *http://sourcefrog.net/weblog/software/languages/C/unused.html*, that explains *UNUSED*.  It is interesting that the author also mangles the unused variable name, so you can't inadvertently use it in the future.

Excerpt:

```
#ifdef UNUSED
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
# define UNUSED(x) UNUSED_ ## x __attribute__((unused))
#elif defined(__LCLINT__)
# define UNUSED(x) /*@unused@*/ x
#else
# define UNUSED(x) x
#endif

void dcc_mon_siginfo_handler(int UNUSED(whatsig))
```

Comment: ... another write-only header macro is just what we need to get a rather benign warning out of the way.

Comment: I'm with you. My code contains `static const char cvsid[] = "$Id$";`. That's short and sweet and readable, but gcc -Wall throws a wobbly on it. I don't want to have to write all this impenetrable code just to suppress that error.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Error: Not Found. The requested URL /weblog/software/languages/C/unused.html was not found on this server."*

Comment: Re *"UNUSED"*: Don't you mean *unused* (the GCC thingy)?

Comment: In any case, can you link to documentation? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 52):

`(void) variable` might work for some compilers.

For C++ code, also see *[Mailbag: Shutting up compiler warnings](http://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/)* where Herb Sutter recommends using:

```
template<class T> void ignore( const T& ) { }

...

ignore(variable);
```

Comment: This works on gcc 4.7.1 with `-std=c99`

Comment: And it works on VS as well.

Comment: (void) works not with nvcc 7.5 with gcc 4.9.2 and C++11 enabled. The herbsutter link with `template<class T> void ignore( const T& ) { }` works great!

Comment: The original question is tagged as C, not C++. As far as I know the (void)var  works in all major C compilers.

Comment: might work in SOME compilers? know a single compiler where it doesn't work?

Comment: @hanshenrik: Yes, see the comments in the linked article: reportedly EDG-based compilers.

Comment: `(void) variable` is cool because it works for any unused variables, not just function parameters like with the accepted answer.

Comment: The question is about C and not C++.

Comment: @usr1234567 I gave an answer for C. (IIRC, at the time this was the *only* answer that suggested the C idiom of `(void) variable`.) Even though it wasn't what the OP asked for, I *additionally* gave an answer for C++ because other readers tend to have a bad practice of using C idioms for C++ even when there are better C++ ones.

Answer (score 49):

#### Tell your compiler using a compiler specific nonstandard mechanism

See individual answers for `__attribute__((unused))`, various `#pragma`s and so on. Optionally, wrap a preprocesor macro around it for portability.

#### Switch the warning off

IDEs can signal unused variables visually (different color, or underline). Having that, compiler warning may be rather useless.

In GCC and Clang, add `-Wno-unused-parameter` option at the end of the command line (after all options that switch unused parameter warning on, like `-Wall`, `-Wextra`).

#### Add a cast to void

```
void foo(int bar) {
    (void)bar;
}
```

As per [jamesdlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417837/what-is-the-best-way-to-suppress-a-unused-variable-x-warning/3418951#3418951) and *[Mailbag: Shutting up compiler warnings](http://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/)*.

#### Do not give the variable a name (C23 and C++ only)

Not allowed in C before the C23 standard, but with a latest compiler (in 2023) and in in C++ (since like forever) one can do

```
void foo(int /*bar*/) {
    ...
}
```

See the [N2480 Allowing unnamed parameters in a function definition (pdf)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2480.pdf) proposal, and check the implementation status at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/compiler_support

GCC 11, Clang 11, and ICX 2022.2 (oneAPI 2022.3) support this.

Comment: I can't believe commenting it out works. That's the way to go if you're using C++ and it is compliant.

Answer (score 19):

If this is really what you want, you could use the *unused* attribute (GCC only), something like:

```
void foo(int __attribute__((__unused__)) bar) {
    ...
}
```

Not just for function parameters, of course, but that's the most common use case, since it might be a callback function for an API where you don't actually need all the input.

Additionally, [GLib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib) has a G_GNUC_UNUSED macro which I believe expands to that attribute.

Answer (score 14):

You can silence the warning using `#pragma`

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused"

int unususedVariable = 1;

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

If you are using GCC, use `#pragma gcc ...`

Comment: Maybe the last line should be `#pragma clang diagnostic pop`

Comment: `#pragma GCC ...`
(it wants upper case GCC)

Answer (score 4):

`#pragma unused <variable>`

Comment: Not portable - generates "unknown pragma" warnings on many compilers

Comment: Paul: That is true and valid, but I'm assuming it doesn't need to be portable since the only reason I can think of to have unused variables is because you have some code commented out for debugging and you still want your (temporary) debugging build to only show warnings you weren't expecting.

Comment: Using this in Xcode4.0 with LLVM 3.0/GCC 4.2 will require you to use parens. `#pragma unused (variable)`

Answer (score 4):

It's a very hackish solution, but try simply assigning the variable to itself.

I think that should fool most compilers into thinking that the variable is used. It should be quite portable too.

Comment: It does fool the compiler into thinking it's used, but you may then get a "code has no effect" warning, depending on the compiler and options.

Comment: the `=` operator might be overloaded with side-effects. you never know. cast to void seems better. eg `(void)my_unused_thing;`

Comment: Clang (and possibly GCC) now has a warning to catch exactly this by now, btw.

Answer (score 4):

The cast to a void is the best approach because it shows that you didn't "accidentally" keep the variable in your code - ie: this function might be an instance where you have a table of function pointers that need the same parameter types and return types, but in this particular table entry you are not using the parameter.

That said, if you don't need it, get rid of it.  ;)

Comment: Can you add an example (that actually compiles (with some specific version of one or more specific compilers))? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to itself:

```
void f(int unused) {
    unused = unused;
}
```

It works in GCC, but Clang needs *-Wno-self-assign*.

---

I think casting to void is the most portable solution: Both GCC and Clang understand this, even with full warnings `-W{all,extra,pedantic}`:

```
(void)unused;
```

Answer (score -9):

Delete the unused variable declaration from the code (pun intended).

(What??? It's what I do: point that the obvious is most likely the best solution.)

Now, from comments on other answers, apparently it's garbage generated from macros. Well, that's a pleonasm.

Solutions:

- refactor that macro to #if declare the variable only if it's really used;
- create another version of the macro that skips the unused variable generation.
- Better still, avoid using macros that bring issues to the code.

Comment: Not possible in this case. It is a macro that "spits out" the variable and I don't want to use it in this case.

Comment: There's other cases as well - e.g if you need to provide a callback function to an external API, but you don't really use/care about some of the parameters you'll get warnings

Comment: nos: Thank you for not assume I'm totally stupid like many of the comments above.

Comment: write more precise questions and you'll get more precise answers

Comment: -1, no substance in the answer. Not even trying to understand the real problem.
nos, good comment, +1

Comment: @Daniel, thanks, because the comments got me false credits, and I was just intending a pun... also, of course I can't understand the real problem from that 2-phrase question. But I'll edit to provide meaningful solution.

Answer (score -10):

If it’s used and you are shipping the project, delete it. Worst, comment it.

Comment: I have these warnings, because the variables are assigned via ASM, so they are not unused but my compiler does not know ...