# Why do we need to cast variable without assigning it?

Tags: c++, variables, casting, void

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why cast an unused value to void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647665/why-cast-an-unused-value-to-void)

for this C++ code:

```
MyClass::myFunc(int val)
{
//some code
(void)val;
//somecode
}
```

why may we need to cast val to void without being assigned to another variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done to shut up the compiler, warning about an unused variable.

Comment: Good stuff, but wouldn't it be better to close duplicates and redirect to the canonical question rather than producing additional, duplicate answers?

Comment: Thanks Tony, really this variable was never used through out the rest of the code ..