# What does this x86 SSE code do?

Tags: opencv, x86, sse, intrinsics

I see this piece of code in OpenCV.

```
__m128i delta = _mm_set1_epi8(-128),
        t = _mm_set1_epi8((char)threshold),
        K16 = _mm_set1_epi8((char)K);
(void)K16;
(void)delta;
(void)t;
```

Can someone explain to me what it does ? All I got is what the sse functions do but what happens in next three line is unclear

Comment: You mean, "Why are all the variables being used as `(void)v`?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why cast an unused value to void?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647665/why-cast-an-unused-value-to-void)

Comment: It's possible they're used as some sort of optimization barriers?

Comment: Git history comment for the changeset that introduce those says "warnings under windows". So, the intention would have been to quiet unused value warning.

Answer (score 0):

Sets the 128 bit value to the signed char input in 8-bit strides:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e14xhyf(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e14xhyf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread your question.  The void casts might be there to stop the compiler from complaining about those vars being unused.  Are they used further on in the code?

Comment: Yes they are used. (Refer to fast.cpp if you have opencv code)