# Portable UNUSED parameter macro used on function signature for C and C++

Tags: c++, c, macros, warnings

I'm interested in creating a macro for eliminating the unused variable warning.

This question describes a way to suppress the unused parameter warning by writing a macro inside the function code:

[Universally compiler independent way of implementing an UNUSED macro in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851075/universally-compiler-independant-way-of-implementing-an-unused-macro-in-c-c)

But I'm interested in a macro that can be used in the function signature:

`void callback(int UNUSED(some_useless_stuff)) {}`

This is what I dug out using Google ([source](http://sourcefrog.net/weblog/software/languages/C/unused.html))

```
#ifdef UNUSED
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
# define UNUSED(x) UNUSED_ ## x __attribute__((unused))
#elif defined(__LCLINT__)
# define UNUSED(x) /*@unused@*/ x
#elif defined(__cplusplus)
# define UNUSED(x)
#else
# define UNUSED(x) x
#endif
```

Can this be further expanded for other compilers?

Edit: For those who can't understand how tagging works: I want a solution for both C and C++. That is why this question is tagged both C and C++ and that is why a C++ only solution is not acceptable.

Comment: There's an easier way, in C++ you can just omit the parameter name.

Comment: @john Yes in C++ you can. In C you can't. I have modified the macro.

Comment: if you aren't interested in the C++ answer don't tag your question C++

Comment: warnings about unused variables are optional features, so also ways to disable that warning will be optional, and as such there are surely some compilers where this is not possible

Comment: Why make it a parameter macro?  Pretty much everything post GCC 2.1 supports the standard `__attribute__` tagging too.

Comment: @jk I'm not interested in answer that will work only in C++.

Comment: @Steve-o If you have a non-parametric version that works on a broad range of compilers, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't have MS VC++ at hand, but I think `#define UNUSED(x) __pragma(warning(suppress:4100)) x` might work.

Comment: The code you posted looks pretty good, can you explain further how it falls short or which particular compiler it doesn't work for?

Comment: @Mark Hmm, works in Intel and Clang. I still need to test MSVC.

Comment: I know from personal experience that MSVC will follow the __cplusplus path and work properly if you're compiling C++. Not sure about using it as a C compiler.

Comment: Why does it have to be on the signature?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be the highest voted answer has changed recently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After testing and following the comments, the original version mentioned in the question turned out to be good enough.

Using: `#define UNUSED(x) __pragma(warning(suppress:4100)) x` (mentioned in comments), might be necessary for compiling C on MSVC, but that's such a weird combination, that I didn't include it in the end.

Comment: This is what i was missing. I'm actually using `#define UNUSED(x) __pragma(warning(suppress: 4100 4101)) x` to be able to decorate both function arguments and local variables unused (`__attribute__((unused))` works the same way in g++). Super cool!

Comment: This didnt work for me with MSVC2013, Still got `C4100` warnings all over.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you choose this over @MattClarkson's answer? This is certainly less portable compared to simple `(void)x`.

Comment: I know why I go in this direction: I have unused parameter in a `constexpr` function which (in VS2015) cannot have multiple statements.

Answer (score 36):

The way I do it is like this:

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)
void foo(const int i) {
    UNUSED(i);
}
```

I've not had a problem with that in Visual Studio, Intel, `gcc` and `clang`.

The other option is to just comment out the parameter:

```
void foo(const int /*i*/) {
  // When we need to use `i` we can just uncomment it.
}
```

Comment: The first answer solves a completely different problem, the second solution works only for C++.

Comment: Casting to void works on unused variables too, unused functions even `(void)printf`. And leaking implementation details by tagging parameters in function signatures tastes funny to begin with.

Answer (score 12):

Just one small thing, better using `__attribute__((__unused__))` as `__attribute__((unused))`, because unused could be somewhere defined as macro, personally I had a few issues with this situation.

But the trick I'm using is, which I found more readable is:

`#define UNUSED(x) (void)x;`

It works however only for the variables, and arguments of the methods, but not for the function itself.

Comment: There are compilers that treat "(void)x;" as still unused. Diab for example.

Answer (score 6):

Across many compilers I have used the following, excluding support for lint.

```
#if (__GNUC__ > 2) || (__GNUC__ == 2 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 4)
#       define PGM_GNUC_UNUSED         __attribute__((__unused__))
#else
#       define PGM_GNUC_UNUSED
#endif
```

Tested compilers:  GCC, Clang, EKOPath, Intel C Compiler / Composer XE, MinGW32 on Cygwin / Linux / MSYS, MinGW-w64 on Cygwin / Linux, Sun ONE Studio / Oracle Solaris Studio, Visual Studio 2008 / 2010.

Example usage:

```
pgm_tsc_init (
        PGM_GNUC_UNUSED pgm_error_t**   error
        )
{
...
}
```

`PGM` is the standard prefix for this C based project.  `GNUC` is the convention from GLib for this attribute.

I think one compile warns about `__attribute__` in certain circumstances but certainly no error.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think that MSVC actually defines `__GNUC__` macro, that would be very weird.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: if it doesn't, then in the context of a `#if` condition, it's as if `__GNUC__` were defined equal to 0. So you'll get the `#else` branch, which Steve-o has tested to work on Visual Studio 2008 and 2010. Not necessarily at the same warning level you're using.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be that is why Cygwin & Mingw use it but MSVC does not, the end result is a working system from Debian 4 / RHEL 4 and newer.

Comment: @Steve-o Well, then this solution is a step backward, since it will only work on GCC. It won't suppress the warning on any other compiler.

Comment: According to the docs at <https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/gcc/>, the first GCC version that accepts `__attribute__((unused))` is 2.7, not 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from C++17 there is now [[[maybe_unused]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused). It's also available in [C23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes/maybe_unused):

```
void callback([[maybe_unused]] int some_useless_stuff) {}
```

Here's the [result on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5ar1WTKhY).