# Does an equivalent of GCC's used attribute exist for MSVC?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, visual-c++, linker

I want to create macros which ensures that a symbol isn't optimised away even though it is unused (this is for reflection code). Does an equivalent for `__attribute__((__used__))` exist in MSVC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Portable UNUSED parameter macro used on function signature for C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090998/portable-unused-parameter-macro-used-on-function-signature-for-c-and-c)

Comment: Can you give an example of such a symbol that you don't want to be optimized away? Are you building as an executable or as a library?

Comment: @cdhowie It's reflection code that exists only in one translation unit, specifically using the RTTR library. It's optimised away, a solution with the used attribute was suggested here: https://github.com/rttrorg/rttr/issues/208#issuecomment-484046407 but of course it's compiler dependant.

Comment: If you are building a static lib the onus is on the importer of the lib.  If you are building a dll then the symbol just needs to be exported.  So I assume you are building an exe - look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/include-force-symbol-references?view=vs-2019

Comment: In MSVC you can use `#pragma comment(linker, "/include:<symbol>")` to force a reference. Inside a macro, use the [`__pragma`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?view=vs-2019) keyword instead.