# Function pointer cast as void without being called

Tags: c, syntax, embedded, compiler-optimization

While perusing some STM32 middleware code, I came across this very odd line and can't parse it.  It's basically,

```c
(void)(foo);
```

It's not a void pointer cast - that would be straightforward.  It's not calling a function and casting its return value as void - that would require a couple more parentheses.  It looks like an rvalue without an lvalue. Is this just a no-op to prevent the function from being optimized away?  Or does it actually do anything?

Here it is in context.

```c
// SVCCTL_EvtAckStatus_t is just an enum typedef

typedef SVCCTL_EvtAckStatus_t (*SVC_CTL_p_EvtHandler_t)(void *p_evt);

void SVCCTL_RegisterCltHandler( SVC_CTL_p_EvtHandler_t pfBLE_SVC_Client_Event_Handler )
{
#if (BLE_CFG_CLT_MAX_NBR_CB > 0)
  // Ignore all this
  SVCCTL_CltHandler.SVCCTL_CltHandlerTable[SVCCTL_CltHandler.NbreOfRegisteredHandler] = pfBLE_SVC_Client_Event_Handler;
  SVCCTL_CltHandler.NbreOfRegisteredHandler++;
#else
  // This is the weird stuff
  (void)(pfBLE_SVC_Client_Event_Handler);
#endif

  return;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any reference of `SVC_CTL_p_EvtHandler_t`? It might help to solve this query.

Comment: I think this has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288844/.  Although that question is for C++ I think the answers are applicable to C as well.

Comment: My guess is that (1) the line itself is there to suppress a warning about `pfBLE_SVC_Client_Event_Handler ` not being used, and (2) as @augurar suggests, the `(void)` is there to suppress some other warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't do anything, except one thing. Stopping the compiler from complaining about unused variables. It is actually being recommended here, on SO, as a portable way of doing it: [Portable UNUSED parameter macro used on function signature for C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090998/portable-unused-parameter-macro-used-on-function-signature-for-c-and-c)

Example:

```c
int somefunction(int a, int b, int c)
{
    (void)(c); // c is reserved for future usage, 
               //stop the compiler from issuing "unused parameter" warning
    return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What this does:

```
(void)(foo);
```

Is cast the expression `foo` to type `void`.  It's a way of saying that an expression is explicitly not being used.

If you look at the definition of the function `SVCCTL_RegisterCltHandler`, you'll see that it takes a parameter named `pfBLE_SVC_Client_Event_Handler`.  This parameter is used in the `#if` preprocessor block.  If the `#if` condition is false, this parameter would otherwise be unused and the compiler would emit a warning that the parameter `pfBLE_SVC_Client_Event_Handler` is unused.

By casting this parameter to `void` in the `#else` block it uses the value and silences the compiler warning.

Comment: To be pedantic, it casts the expression `(foo)` to type `void`.

Answer (score 0):

It's to prevent the compiler from complaining about foo being unused. That's literally it. It's like the `maybe_unused` attribute in C++.