# UNUSED macro warning

Tags: c, macros, warnings

So I found this  [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851075/universally-compiler-independent-way-of-implementing-an-unused-macro-in-c-c/4851173#4851173) on SO:

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(sizeof((x), 0))
```

and this (still) produces the following warning:

> main.c:11:36: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
>       #define UNUSED(x) (void)(sizeof((x), 0))

Whereas the simpler version, a normal `void` cast: `#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)` is warning-free.

What could be the reason behind it? In general warnings are a sign of high-risk situations. Is here the given warning really useful?

I am interested in C-explanation.

Comment: The macro as you show it, using the comma operator, doesn't cause `x` to be evaluated at runtime while with `(void)(x)` it is. If `x` has some side-effect then that will happen with your version of the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro seems inappropriate for your compiler at the current warning level.

You could use this simpler version:

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(sizeof(x))
```

`x` will not be evaluated either but is *used* so the compiler should not complain about `x` being unused, not about the left hand side of the `,` operator being unused in the expression.

Comment: `UNUSED(x) (void)(x)` is also *used* why then `UNUSED(x) (void)(sizeof(x))`

Comment: The first evaluates `x`, so any side effects take place.  For example `UNUSED(system("del /Y *.*"));` is not safe, whereas the second does not even evaluate `x`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you linked, is also linking to where this solution is from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030959/will-a-variablename-c-statement-be-a-no-op-at-all-times/4030983#4030983)
The actual source of this solution is saying that it still does produce warnings and is giving proper solutions.

Comment: `((void)(true ? 0 : ((x), void(), 0)))` is C++, since there are no real booleans in C.

Comment: @user8 i guess part of why your macro gives a warning is because it is from C++. But for your question about how "useful" the warning is you get:
Something not having an effect, will not cause any errors.
But you are using it because you don't want warnings.
You can go for the complicated version of
`#define USE(x) ((void)(1 ? 0 : ((x), NULL, 0)))`
Or the simple `#define UNUSED(x) (void)(sizeof(x))`

Comment: I don't think `void()` and `NULL` are the same and with what is `UNUSED(x) (void)(sizeof(x))` better than `UNUSED(x) (void)(x)`