# assert return-value, but run either way

Tags: c++, coding-style, compiler-warnings, assert, boolean-expression

Typically, when I erase an element from a set, I want to assert that it was actually erased:
ie

```
assert(s.erase(e));
```

but then the element doesn't get erased when NDEBUG is set.  But if I write

```
bool removed = s.erase(e);
assert(removed);
```

the compiler complains that 'removed' is unused when NDEBUG is set.

How can I do this right?

---

I ended up just creating a utility method:

```
inline void run_and_assert(bool b) {
    assert(b);
}
```

now I can say

```
run_and_assert(s.erase(e));
```

Are there any drawbacks to this?  It seems simpler to me than luiscubal's solution

Comment: Many compilers provide a `verify()` function/macro that does what you want.

Comment: the very obvious drawback is now you get told only that `b` failed, instead of whatever condition you were actually asserting...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote my own like luiscubal's suggestion except instead of ugly #define's I made a short inline method:

```
inline void assert_always_execute(bool x) {
    assert(x);
}
```

Comment: ...which still complains about `unused parameter 'x'` when compiled with `NDEBUG`, and thus solves the problem, how?

Comment: and also, the very obvious drawback is now you get told only that `b` failed, instead of whatever condition you were actually asserting originally...

Answer (score 8):

The first example is wrong because the assert expression will be removed when NDEBUG is defined, so `s.erase(e)` won't be called at all.

**The argument of `assert` should NEVER have side-effects.**

The second approach is better, though the warning might indeed be annoying, but [there are ways to silence the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417837/what-is-the-best-way-to-supress-unused-variable-x-warning).

Alternatively you could come up with your own assert statement that always executes the code.

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert_always_execute(x) (x)
#else
#define assert_always_execute(x) assert(x)
#endif
```